# Difference between executing in JS console and as script

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, magnific-popup

I have a website with links, which should open a Lightbox (3rd party plugin Magnific Popup / jquery). After manipulating content on the site, i have to re-execute some Javascript of the Lightbox plugin, so that it recognizes the new links as links to lightboxes.

```js
function loadLightbox() {
    console.log("Lightbox start"); // for debugging
    $('a.img').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        closeBtnInside: false,
        image: {
            titleSrc: 'title_off',
            markup:
                '<div class="mfp-figure">' +
                '<div class="mfp-close"></div>' +
                '<div class="mfp-title"></div>' +
                '<div class="mfp-img"></div>' +
                '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">' +
                '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' // Popup HTML markup. `.mfp-img` div will be replaced with img tag, `.mfp-close` by close button
        }
    });
    console.log("Lightbox end"); // for debugging
}
```

I have a function, which manipulates the content on the page `changeSuggestion()`. Because I want to have the content changed every 6 secondes, I use the `setInterval` function.

```js
setInterval(function () { changeSuggestion(); loadLightbox(); }, 6000);
```

My problem is, that it changes every 6s the content on the page, but the lightbox thing doesn't work (although the lightbox function produces output). But when I copy the `loadLightbox()` function into the firefox console and execute it, the lightbox in does work until it changes the content again. So my question is, **what is the difference between executing via `setInterval` and executing in the Firefox javascript console?**

**Edit:**
`changeSuggestion`: opens a JSON file, and produces html-formatted output, the page is manipulated by `$("#blogSuggestion").html(result)`

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

function changeSuggestion() {
    $.getJSON("blog/blog.json", function (data) {
        var n = 0,
            showId,
            entry,
            result;
        $.each(data.blogentries, function (key, entry) {
            if (entry.id > n) {
                n = entry.id;
            }
        });
        showId = randomIntFromInterval(0, n - 1);
        if (data.blogentries[showId]) {
            entry = data.blogentries[showId];
            if (entry.type === "text") {
                result = "<a class=\"" + entry.type + "\" title=\"" + entry.title  + "\" href= \"#blogID" + entry.id + "\"><b>" + entry.title + "</b>";

            } else {
                result = "<a class=\"" + entry.type + "\" title=\"" + entry.title  + "\" href= \"" + entry.source + "\"><b>" + entry.title + "</b>";
            }
            if (entry.content) {
                result = result + "<br /><p>" + getExcerpt(entry.content, 20, '') + "</p><div id= \"blogID" + entry.id +  "\" class=\"blogLightbox mfp-hide\"><img  alt=\"" + entry.title + "\" src=\"" + entry.thumb + "\" ><div class=\"blogText\"><h3>" + entry.title + "</h3><p>" + entry.content + "</p></a></div></div>";
            } else {
                result = result + '<img  alt=\"' + entry.title + '\" src=\"' + entry.thumb + '\"></a>';
            }
            $("#blogSuggestion").html(result);
        } else {
            console.log("Nothing with ID: " + showId);
        }
    });
```

**Edit:**
As its written in the comments, the content is changed asynchronously. If I put the `asynchronously` function into the body of `changeSuggestion` it works!

Comment: What does the `changeSuggestion` function do? Does it load content asyncronously?

Comment: The inestimably astute Guffa was correct in his guess: your function expects (implicitly) that your "changeSuggestion" function will do its work immediately, but that's not the case! Thus your "loadLightbox" function is running before any of those `<a>` elements have been added to the page.

Comment: Oh thats great, thanks for your answer. When I put the Lightbox Function into the body of my changeSuggestion function, it works :) Thanks a lot!